# How to stop a function that is set to an interval instantly

Tags: javascript, function, exit

I am currently working on a controller for an RGB LED strip and writing on the effects, but I have the problem where I cannot stop the effects instantly.

I've already tried the following, but that doesn't stop the effect right where it is. It only stops the effect after it's completed.

```
function jump3() {
  rgb.red = 255
  rgb.green = 0
  rgb.blue = 0

  socket.emit("rgbLed", rgb)

  var step1 = setTimeout(() => {
    rgb.red = 0
    rgb.green = 255
    rgb.blue = 0
    socket.emit("rgbLed", rgb)
  }, 1000);

  var step2 = setTimeout(() => {
    rgb.red = 0
    rgb.green = 0
    rgb.blue = 255
    socket.emit("rgbLed", rgb)
  }, 2000);
}
```

What I've tried:

```
function jump3() {
  if (stopEffect == 1) {
    clearTimeout(step1)
    clearTimeout(step2)
    stopEffect = 0
    return
  }
  rgb.red = 255
  rgb.green = 0
  rgb.blue = 0

  socket.emit("rgbLed", rgb)

  var step1 = setTimeout(() => {
    rgb.red = 0
    rgb.green = 255
    rgb.blue = 0
    socket.emit("rgbLed", rgb)
  }, 1000);

  var step2 = setTimeout(() => {
    rgb.red = 0
    rgb.green = 0
    rgb.blue = 255
    socket.emit("rgbLed", rgb)
  }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: clearTimeout takes an int that represents the timer ID. not sure passing a function there will do anything useful.

Comment: @rlemon what do u think should i do instead?

Comment: if you want to stop a timer you need the timerID so you can remove it from the pool. @Jan has already suggested one way, which is to just move the variables up a scope. Then they will not be overwritten each time the function is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to place the declaration of the timer-variables outside the function.

```js
var stopAction = false;
var timer = false;

function action() {
  if (stopAction) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    stopAction = false;
    return;
  }
  timer = setTimeout(function(){
    let output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.textContent = output.textContent + 'StackOverflow! ';
  }, 1000);
}

document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', action);
document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', function(){
  stopAction = true;
  action();
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="start">Start</button> 
  <button id="stop">Stop</button>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: same issue with that

Comment: I updated the code in my answer. It is now a executable example. @MavRick